# $urlRouterProvider.rule doesn't work

Tags: angularjs

I'm experiencing a weird issue with $urlRouterProvider.
In theory I should be able to see the 'here' message log every time the url changes, but I can only see that when the url typed is not in the 'state' list.
Can you telle me what's wrong with this code and why $urlRouterProvider.rule is not executed every url change?

This is my code for the stateProviderConfig:

```
angular.module('stateProviderConfig', [])
 .config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise( function($injector) {
  var $state = $injector.get('$state');
  $state.go('app.dashboard');
});

$urlRouterProvider.rule(function ($injector, $location) {
  console.log('here');
});

$stateProvider
.state('app', {
  abstract: true,
  url: '/app',
  templateUrl: 'views/tmpl/app.html',
})
.state('app.404', {
  url: '/404',
  controller: 'Err404Controller',
  templateUrl: 'views/tmpl/404.html'
...
...
}]);
```

Comment: how you are navigating to states?

Comment: refer this: http://plnkr.co/edit/4XMBfuvarfakjvX85w94?p=preview

Comment: I'm just changing the url. $urlRouterProvider.rule should be executed every time the url changes but it doesn't